# Latex insertnavigation - dots in two lines

Tags: latex, beamer

I am trying to adapt a given navigation in my Beamer document, such that the dots representing subsections are not squeezed into one line.

I tried to implement a small example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{%
    \vskip35pt
    \centering
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \vspace*{0.5ex}
    \textcolor{white}{\hrule height 2pt}
    \bigskip
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
    \vspace*{1ex}
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
    \vspace*{1ex}
    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\newenvironment{withoutheadline}{%
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.9cm]{\paperwidth}
            \begin{minipage}{0.2\paperwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.19\paperwidth]{XY.pdf}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{minipage}
        \color{black}\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt} 
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \colorbox{black}{\begin{minipage}[c][0.4cm]{\textwidth}%
            \hfill
        \end{minipage}\hspace{-6pt}}
    }
}{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{\begin{minipage}[c][1.1cm]{\paperwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\paperwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.19\paperwidth]{XYZ.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{1\paperwidth}
        % insert the default navigation (miniframes)
            \insertnavigation{0.75\paperwidth}
            \vskip4pt
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \color{black}\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt} 
    }


\title[Short Title]{Public Transport Optimization}
\author{XY}
\institute[Chair for EMC]{
    Chair of XY \\
    XY
}
\mode<presentation>{\keywords{Put some keywords here, separated by commas, e.g. Non-Technical Project, Academic Writing}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    % \maketitle also works in the article mode
    % \titlepage only works for presentation
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=inhalt]{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection*{}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<presentation>{Introduction}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction 1}
    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction 2}
    
\end{frame}

\section{Main Part}

\subsection{Mainpart1}
\begin{frame}{Mainpart1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Mainpart2}
\begin{frame}{Mainpart2}
    
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

If you compile it, you can see an example of what my problem is in the headline: the dots under the main part are in one row and if I add more than three subsections, the dots become invisible - I would therefore like to have the dots in a row, or in two parallel lines.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can see if you use any special option like `compress`

Comment: I tried to include an example @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz As the original code is quite long, I hope that the necessary sections are included in my example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If I run your example, the miniframes are spread out over multiple lines https://i.stack.imgur.com/c35qz.png Can you show a screenshot of what you get instead? Or maybe I misunderstand your question and you want them in a single line? In this case use `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}`

Comment: Yes, the compress command is what I was looking for - now it works!

Answer (score 2):

To show the miniframes from all subsections in a single line, you can use the `compress` option of the beamer class:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}


\setbeamerfont{title page}{family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{%
    \vskip35pt
    \centering
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \vspace*{0.5ex}
    \textcolor{white}{\hrule height 2pt}
    \bigskip
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
    \vspace*{1ex}
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
    \vspace*{1ex}
    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\newenvironment{withoutheadline}{%
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.9cm]{\paperwidth}
            \begin{minipage}{0.2\paperwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.19\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{minipage}
        \color{black}\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt} 
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \colorbox{black}{\begin{minipage}[c][0.4cm]{\textwidth}%
            \hfill
        \end{minipage}\hspace{-6pt}}
    }
}{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{\begin{minipage}[c][1.1cm]{\paperwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\paperwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.19\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{1\paperwidth}
        % insert the default navigation (miniframes)
            \insertnavigation{0.75\paperwidth}
            \vskip4pt
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \color{black}\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt} 
    }


\title[Short Title]{Public Transport Optimization}
\author{XY}
\institute[Chair for EMC]{
    Chair of XY \\
    XY
}
\mode<presentation>{\keywords{Put some keywords here, separated by commas, e.g. Non-Technical Project, Academic Writing}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    % \maketitle also works in the article mode
    % \titlepage only works for presentation
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=inhalt]{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection*{}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<presentation>{Introduction}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction 1}
    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction 2}
    
\end{frame}

\section{Main Part}

\subsection{Mainpart1}
\begin{frame}{Mainpart1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Mainpart2}
\begin{frame}{Mainpart2}
    
\end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

[image]